# cloudkit "Your request contains more than the maximum number of items in a single request (400)"

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

When doing a query with

```
    [publicDatabase performQuery:query
                inZoneWithID:nil
           completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {...
```

I get the following error, if the returned results count is 100 or higher

```
70] Error: <CKError 0x170641a70: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1020); "Your request contains more than the maximum number of items in a single request (400)">
```

I am in developer mode with the backend. Does this mean, I can't do a query with more than 100-200 returned objects? That not much...   Is it any other ClouKits deployment mode?

Answer (score 2):

Look for CKQueryOperation in the API.   it will give you a cursor that you can iterate through all the results, be sure to set your operaation.resultsLimit to something manageable or you will get the same error.